# Generate Random value from a collection in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

To make it simple, i have a list of Products.

Now i want to create a method and will generate me a random Product each time.

How do i achieve that.

Answer (score 7):

assuming you have an array products of Products, then you can select a random Product by the following code:

```
randon_product = products.sample
```

Answer (score 2):

In 1.9 you have `[].sample` and in 1.8 you have `[].choice`. There is a gem called backports that harmonizes this and other differences, or you could do it yourself like this:

```
class Array
  def sample
    choice
  end
end unless Array.method_defined? :sample
```

Comment: +1 for showing off the do-it-yourself technique.  Very useful.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby 1.8, the simplest way is probably `Array#choice`

```
irb(main):005:0> 5.times {puts (1..100).to_a.choice} 
14
92
84
65
9
=> 5
irb(main):006:0> [5,3,234,234,3,2,2,2].choice
=> 3
```

**EDIT** In Ruby 1.9 it is called `sample`, not `choice`.

Comment: See DigitalRoss's answer for a nice way to allow the use of `sample` in all Ruby versions.  [Here's the change log for Ruby 1.9.1 showing that choice was removed](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/repos/ruby/branches/ruby_1_9_1/NEWS)

Answer (score 0):

```
array = [product1, product2, product3]

puts array[rand(array.size)]
```